# Problema al leer datos excel

Tags: vb.net

Quiero importar un Excel entero a un DataGridView.

```
Public Sub Excel()
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection

    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    Try
        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

        If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Form1) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fi.FullName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + FileName + "$]", conn)
            Dim ds As New DataTable("Excel")
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dta.Fill(ds)
            Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
            conn.Close()

            With Form1.DataGridView1
                .RowHeadersVisible = False
                .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Direcciones"
            End With

            Form1.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Se vé que tengo problemas con el nombre del archivo o algo parecido...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento he copiado el contenido a un bloc de notas y lo leo desde ahí línea a línea, pero para futuras ocasiones me gustaría saber hacerlo... Gracias! :)

Comment: Es la versión del Acceso a base de datos. Busca el que corresponda a la versión de office que quieres manejar.

Comment: El error lo que te dice es que estás intentado abrir un archivo cuya extensión acaba es `.xlsx$`. ¿No debería ser solo `.xlsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + FileName + "$]", conn)
```

En esta linea debes eliminar *$*.
Prueba con esto:

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + FileName "]", conn)
```

Comment: Lo probé pero me daba un error diferente y me dí cuenta de que no estaba usando la versión de Excel que declaro en el código. La solución es lo que comentas. Gracias!

Comment: Por nada, sería de mucha ayuda marcar como respuesta correcta para futuros visitantes del post.